# jquery: adding nav list to sliding divs

Tags: jquery, html, navigation, scrollto

Hello — First and foremost I'm fairly new to jquery so your extended expertise is greatly appreciated.

DEMO: http://www.transcendspace.com/beta/

I'd like to generate a nav for my divs: 1|2|3|4|5 etc. that would highlight the number depending on which div is active. Ideally the highlight would work in combination with my left/right arrows.

CODE: `

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).resize(function () {
      resizePanel();
  });
});

function resizePanel() {

    width = $(window).width();
    height = $(window).height();

    mask_width = width * $('.item').length;

    $('#debug').html(width  + ' ' + height + ' ' + mask_width);
    $('#wrapper, .item').css({width: width, height: height});
    $('#mask').css({width: mask_width, height: height});
    $('#wrapper').scrollTo($('a.selected').attr('href'), 0);    
}


function scrollToPosition(element) {
   if (element !== undefined) {
        $("#wrapper").scrollTo(element, 800, {});
   }
}



$(function() {
     //Create an Array of posts
     var posts = $('.item');
     var position = 0; //Start Position
     var next = $('#next');
     var prev = $('#prev').hide();

 //Better performance to use Id selectors than class selectors
     next.click(function(evt) {
     //Scroll to next position
         prev.show();
         scrollToPosition(posts[position += 1]);

         if (position === posts.length - 1) {
             next.hide();
         }
});

prev.click(function(evt) {
    //Scroll to prev position    
    next.show();
scrollToPosition(posts[position -= 1]);

    if (position === 0) {
    prev.hide();
    }
});

}); 

 </script>'
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `.ready()` handler, create a list of items number:

```
var len = posts.length
var $ul = $('<ul id="navItems">');
for (var i=0; i<len; i++) {
    $('<li data-item="' + i+ '">' + (i+1) + '</li>')
        .click(function(e) {
            // go to this item when  you click
            // get the item num using $(this).data('item');
        })
        .appendTo($ul);
}
$ul.insertAfter($('#prev'));
```

You can style the list with css to make it horizontal:

```
#navItems { list-style: none; display: inline-block; }
   #navItems li { display: inline-block; width: 15px; height: 15px; }
   #navItems li { zoom: 1;  } // for old IE
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/8xnEu/) for you to play with.

---

**Implementing the click**

Here is a piece of code to implement the scroll when clicking on an "item".

It should be a bit easier to save the ID of the corresponding `.item` in the attribute `data-itemid`, afterall we do what we want :-)

```
for (var i=0; i<len; i++) {

    // save the item id and not just the index
    $('<li data-itemid="' + posts[i].id + '">' + (i+1) + '</li>')
        .click(function(e) {

            // get the data from data-itemid attibute
            var itemid = $(this).data('itemid');

            // use your scrollToPosition method
            // with our 'itemid' we can get the element using the ID selector
            scrollToPosition($('#' + itemid));

        })
        .appendTo($ul);
    }

}
```

I have updated the fiddle as well.

---

**A few note about your code**

- You have two `ready` handlers actually in your code. One explicit at the top `$(document).ready()` and `$(function() {...})`. They actually both work the `ready` event so you should only keep one. It works with two but it makes your code less manageable.
- Always do this: declare first your variables with `var`, then your local functions and then do what you have to do. Respecting as much as possible this canvas will help you read your code because you expect things to be there or there.
- Prefix your jquery variable with `$`: `var $posts = $('.item');`. When you then see a variable, you know what it contains (or supposed to) by its name.
- jQuery is about chaining.

Instead of doing this:

```
var next = $('#next');
next.click(function(e) {...});
```

Do this:

```
var $next = $('#next').click(...).addClass(...).show();
var $prev = $('#prev').click(...).toggle((position > 0));
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I've gone ahead and updated my code and it is grabbing my items. I tried to add my call to action in the .click using:`$(this).data.scrollTo('item');` but that unfortunately didn't work — Again, i'm new to this but I greatly appreciate your help. UPDATED: [link](http://www.transcendspace.com/beta)

Comment: To get the `data-item` value you have to do `.data('item')`. Check the [.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/) documentation.

Comment: I have updated my answer with more info. Please accept the answer if it helped, would you ?

Comment: Its obvious this is a bit over my head with regards to syntax/the fundamentals of jquery but I greatly appreciate your time/expertise. 1. How can I get my arrows and my links to work together? For example link 1 should be in a 'selected' state since that's the first div that is active. When you click 'next' it would move the selected state to '2' and so on. Another variable to consider with this is if you select '5' or '1' in the list the arrows should become enabled /or disabled. First and foremost however, Instead of popping up an alert how can I make it actually scrollTo a selected item?

Comment: You can use css classes to achieve that. In your next and prev click handlers, use `removeClass('active')` on all items and `addClass('active')` to the current item. You should be able to find examples on the web or on SO. For the part with alert(), I have provided the code already (using your scrollToPosition function), check the answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. Time profit when you use ID instead of class is too small for non-cycle usage, and doesn't worth of confusing yourself adding increment to all div-clones.
2. For getting know which key is pressed you can use keydown/keyup - http://jsfiddle.net/RsFpJ/4/ - try to type anything in field and you will see which code button has
3. Try to use jsfiddle.net for sharing your code example - it's much easier to help in such case, because we don't have to retype your code.
4. You can build numbers to div elements with jquery's [index](http://api.jquery.com/index/)() function http://jsfiddle.net/RsFpJ/5/, native javascript's length and for

**jQuery**

```
    var objs = $(".key");
    var navHtml = '';
    for (i = 0; i < objs.length; i++) {
        navHtml += '<span>'+(i+1)+'</span>' ;
    }

    $('#nav').html(navHtml);

    $('#nav span').click(function(){
        // index of span inside set of spans, starting from 0;
        var eqIndex = $('#nav span').index(this);
        objs.eq(eqIndex).css("border-color","red");        
    });
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="key"></div>
<div class="key"></div>
<div class="key"></div>
<div class="key"></div>
<div class="key"></div>

<div id="nav"></div>
```